# A question on the properties of wave equations

Tags: waves, frequency, speed, wavelength

When you change

$$y(x,t)=A\sin(kx-ωt+φ) $$

into

$$y(x,t)=A\sin(2kx-2ωt+φ), $$

does it double the wavelength because $k$ changes into $2k$ and double the frequency since ω is doubled?

If this is the case, what would the graph of the wave look like?

Since $v=λf$

will the wave graph have double the frequency and wavelength?

Comment: k is not wavelength but wave"number". They have different units.

Comment: The wavelength gets cut in half.

Answer (score 1):

You are doubling both the wavenumber $k$ and the frequency $\omega$. Since wavenumber and wavelength are related by $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$, you are therefore doubling the frequency and halving the wavelength. Since $v=\lambda f$, this new wave will travel at the same speed (one factor doubled, one factor halved). In general, preserving the propagation speed only happens when you multiply wavenumber and frequency by the same factor.